# filter id contains specific string in Flask sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

when we use sqlalchemy we can use like below to query about string field contains specific string.

```
query.filter(Post.title.like("%" + searchKey + "%"))
```

If I want to do this with id field(Integer), how to do it?

For example I want to get the posts that contains searchKey inside its id.
if searchKey is "12", then the posts that has the id like 1234, 312, 3128 will be returned.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to cast you integer field to a string and then perform your like.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast
from sqlalchemy import String

query.filter(cast(Post.title, String).like("%" + searchKey + "%"))
```